# Selecting X Number of rows or lower if X number of rows not available

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to select and inset X rows into a temp table at each execution, I have numbered the rows. However, I tried using PERCENT and TOP but not getting the desire results.

Note: I am not trying to get specific number of rows **between certain numbers**. I just need to get a fix number, and if the number of available rows is below the select request, then get less but do not exceed.

I assigned the row numbers like this:

```
WITH GetRecordByIncrement AS
(
SELECT 
     [RowNumber] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UserID ASC)
    ,[Column1]
    ,[Column2]
    ,[Column3]
     FROM MySchema.MyTable
)
```

How would I get, example: 100 or less rows? This does not work using the row number.

Comment: I must be missing something. Why is `TOP` not working for you? `SELECT TOP 100 Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM MySchema.MyTable`

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was using the TOP wrongly causing some records to get left out. I switched the TOP to return records based on a unique identifier. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Sorry, you probably noticed already that I forgot the `ORDER BY` clause in my example: `SELECT TOP 100 Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM MySchema.MyTable ORDER BY UserID`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE ( c1 INT, c2 INT, c3 INT );

;
WITH    MyRows
          AS ( SELECT TOP 100
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY message_id ) AS RowNum ,
                        message_id ,
                        severity
               FROM     sys.messages
             )
    INSERT  INTO @Table
            ( c1 ,
              c2 ,
              c3
            )
            SELECT  RowNum ,
                    message_id ,
                    severity
            FROM    MyRows;

SELECT  *
FROM    @table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
WITH GetRecordByIncrement AS
(
SELECT
     [RowNumber] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UserID ASC)
    ,[Column1]
    ,[Column2]
    ,[Column3]
     FROM MySchema.MyTable
)
select * from GetRecordByIncrement  where [RowNumber]<=desirednumber
```